# Is web notifications possible in a local Wi-fi network without internet?

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, web-notifications

I found that Web notifications have been supported by chrome browser. This needs the google clod messaging to be integrated with the website. So, the question is, is it possible to build a push notification server for web apps that gives notifications for mobile and desktops chrome browsers. The scenario is a closed wi-fi connection without connecting to internet. I also found that push notifications works on GSM. So I would like to know whether this is feasible ?

Comment: push notifications are delivered when the receiver has internet connectivity .

Comment: Ya I understand that, So you saying it is not possible to build a push notification server locally and deliver notifications from a wi-fi?

Comment: The W3C Push API / Web Push uses a browser push service which is in the cloud: so you can't send "real" push notifications without internet access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this using the Google Play Services, as that by definition requires routing through Google's servers.

You could, however, have a local server with a socket connection, and just send and receive data over that.

Comment: So, by local server technique, you mean the websockets ? But this will only work when the user is using the webapp right? . Is there any other way ?. Would like to know a detailed explanation.

Comment: ? Do you mean the socket as such websockets ? or some other push notifications kind of socket